# How to generate XML "xs:id" value in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I create a XML file in my application generated with the help with classes I created with XSD.exe from some schema files.

Now I was finally able to validate my XML against the schema and it tells me that some IDs I was using have the wrong format. I used C# GUIDs and the simpleType definition looks like this:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="idDocument">
    <xs:annotation>
        ...
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:ID">
      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

I then searched for the definition of "xs:ID" and found one on: http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_ID.html which says:

> Based on xsd:NCName
>
> Pattern: [\i-[:]][\c-[:]]* (Defined in type xsd:NCName)
>
> White Space: collapse (Defined in type xsd:token)

Some example IDs I have look like this:

- _Q76m-TfmEeKLm53bgNs7IQ
- _Q8qN1jfmEeKLm53bgNs7IQ
- _3hVxYDfiEeKLm53bgNs7IQ

I don't like to reinvent the wheel and guess that maybe there is something already available in C# that lets me generate such an xml-ID that I can use. But so far I found nothing.

Does anybody know if such a thing already exists?

Comment: `"_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("d")` should do fine. The problem is not that the IDs must be generated according to some algorithm, but that they must be valid names, which means they cannot begin with a digit, nor contain `{` or `}` (as GUIDs may well do).

Comment: You are right, this was the issue. It works with your proposed solution, you should post it as an answer.